# openconnect doesn't work after suspend, I have to reboot to get it to work again

Tags: networking, networkmanager, suspend, wpa-supplicant, openconnect

I have the following situation:

I am connected to a VPN via openconnect.
I disconnect (for example because I suspend my computer), and then when I try to reconnect, openconnect gives me the following.

```
getaddrinfo failed for host '<HOST>': Temporary failure in name resolution
Failed to open HTTPS connection to <HOST>
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

When I reboot my computer, it works again.

I am using wpa_supplicant.
I tried to restart wpa_supplicant, but it still doesn't work.
Back when I used NetworkManager, I had the same problem, but contrary to my wpa_supplicant setup, I was able to reconnect with openconnect after restarting NetworkManager.
So apparently, restarting NetworkManager resets more things (as NetworkManager handles way more things than wpa_supplicant alone, at least as I understand it), and that way I was always able to use openconnect successfully again.

What part of the rebooting can I manually do to solve my problem, without having to do a full reboot?  What does NetworkManager do that wpa_supplicant doesn't when I restart them?

Comment: Right after unsuspending the system and, say, after trying and failing once at reconnecting, can you run `ip route` and also dump the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`?